# concatenate a string in android and me the correct result

Tags: java, android

```
public void populateSetDate(int yyyy, int mm, int dd) {
    String a = " ";
    if (dd < 10) {
        a = "0" + dd;
    }
    else {

    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        a = "0" + mm;
    }   
   else
   {   

   }   
    EditText aEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    aEdit.setText(a + "/" + a +  "/" + yyyy);
}
```

---

```
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int yyyy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mm =  calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: You should make your question more clear.

Comment: Okay you posted some code. What's the question?

Comment: What you trying to do...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well that's just all sorts of wrong. I would recommend using SimpleDateFormat: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
    SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    return output.format(date);
```

date being a Date object.

Edit: To fix the original code:

```
public void populateSetDate(int yyyy, int mm, int dd) {
    EditText aEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    aEdit.setText(String.format("%02d/%02d/%d", dd, mm, yyyy);
}
```

Comment: Don't know what the down votes are for, it's pretty clear what he's trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You need a "month" string and a "day" string, and you weren't setting the "else" string to anything, so anything over "10" was blank:

```
public void populateSetDate(int yyyy, int mm, int dd) {
    String a = " ";
    if (dd < 10) {
        a = "0" + dd;
    }
    else {
        a = "" + dd;
    }
    String b = " ";
    if (mm < 10) {
        b = "0" + mm;
    else {
        b = "" + dd;
    }      
    EditText aEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    aEdit.setText(b + "/" + a +  "/" + yyyy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what u trying to do but when you contcate two string then do like this.

```
text=text+"add new text in string"
```